# How to make picom use the NVIDIA card with PRIME for blurring effects?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, i3, gpu, picom

I use picom to manage the transparency and blur effects of my terminals, using i3 on Arch Linux. The backend I use is `glx`, though I don't mind changing it to something else if needed.

My laptop has hybrid graphics, with an integrated Intel card and an NVIDIA discrete one. I've installed PRIME [following the Arch Linux wiki instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME#PRIME_render_offload).

From what I understand, the default OpenGL renderer is the integrated card. However, I know that the blur effects could be a little bit expensive, so I would like the NVIDIA card to take the load for this one.

Is there a way for me to keep PRIME and to delegate the action of computing the blur to the NVIDIA card? By changing the backend, or changing the OpenGL configuration? And is there a way for me to know whether picom actually use the NVIDIA card (using `nvidia-smi` for instance?)

Note that I'm perfectly happy with not using my NVIDIA card otherwise, I don't run games or anything on this laptop.